# VsCode php.validate.executablePath, after insalled XAMPP

Tags: php, linux, visual-studio-code, xampp, php-extension

i'm trying to set the certain path for the php extension in my vscode (using linux)

i started installing the XAMPP
and after it..i tried to use the extension writing some php scripts(php extension INTELLISENSE and DEBUG), but the extension is not working properly and it's showing that error:

Cannot validate since /usr/bin/php is not a valid php executable. Use the setting 'php.validate.executablePath' to configure the PHP executable.

i tried to set it using que path which is provided by vscode documentation, but it's still no working.

Can anyone help me !! please!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution, typing in terminal

'`whereis php`'

that returns the absolute path for set it in the vscode extension

/opt/lampp/bin/php

Then, setting the path in the follow line

```
php.validate.executablePath: "/opt/lampp/bin/php",
```

So, I hope this solution is helping someone behind the screen.

Comment: just in case someone comes across the issue I faced after doing that: Dont forget to run the XAMPP server

Answer (score 6):

**Php path in windows**

Typing in terminal

`where php`

And it'll gives the path as (in my case)

`C:\xampp\php\php.exe`

Comment: C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe  worked on my win11 home edition.

Answer (score 4):

Just extending the answer by @Reinaldo Duguet with a ton of thanks to him !

If you are using Xampp, the PHP path can be found by running the local server and then typing localhost in the browser. This will open the Xampp dashboard. Click on phpinfo() and there you will get the exact path shown as
Configuration File (php.ini) Path = /opt/lampp/etc

Please note that the path may very as per the PHP installation in your system. So you may have to use the respective path shown with above ways.

Then, to let VSCode know this path, open settings in VSCode and search for "PHP debug" and click on the PHP > Debug:Executable Path setting

Add the following line at the first place after "{" telling VSCode where PHP is installed in the system.

"php.validate.executablePath": "/opt/lampp/etc",

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xampp, the PHP path can be found by running the local server and then typing

the correct version C:/xampp/php/php.exe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Aren't you just repeating a previous answer ?

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP isn't the best option for linux and i wouldn't recommend it.

Assuming this is not the problem, here is how to do :

1. find php executable

```
whereis php
```

2. Check your vscode installation. ***You want to make sure it's not using flatpak*** (it runs in a container and it would mess up everything)
3. go in vscode settings, search for `php` and set `"php.debug.executablePath": "/your path/php"`

If it still doesn't work, this might be a permission problem. Then :

1. copy the php executable in your user folder

```
sudo cp original_path/php /your_user_folder/php
```

2. add permissions

```
sudo chmod 777 /your_user_folder/php
```

If none of above worked, at this point, you may want to use a VM.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add a possibility here that ended up being my issue in case it helps someone else in the future. My issue was that I was using a Debian based distro and installed VSCode through the software app which relies on Snap apparently. Snap runs the programs in a sandbox and prevents them from seeing other locations on the computer. My solution was that I uninstalled the shop version and installed VScode manually via downloading directly from the website. After that, everything works as expected.